# object.js with state in react ( Cannot read property 'map' of undefined)

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am using js Object and in this object I have 3 section of data : first section (New Arrival) second section (Best Seller) and third section (Special Offer), when I use array.map() to loop the data this error happen [image]

I saw many problems here like mine but no solution be right with me

this is the data
[image]

and this is the code

```
import ProductItem from './ProductItem';
import {getAll} from '../../api/product';

class Products extends Component {
   state ={
      products :[]
   };
componentDidMount(){
    getAll().then(data =>{
        this.setState({
            products :data
        })
        
    });
}
render() {
    
    return (
        <div className="container">
            <div className="head-with-border"><h2>New Arrival</h2></div>
            <div className="products">
                {this.state.products.bestSeller.map(product =>
                    <div className={"product"} key={product.id}>
                    <ProductItem product={product}/>
                    </div>
                )}
            
            </div>

        </div>
    )
  }
 }
 export default Products;
```

this is consols.log(data)
[image]

and this is getAll function
[image]

Comment: Your `state.products` is defined as an array. Arrays typically don't have a property `bestSeller`. Although I don't know what `data` in your `componentDidMount` handler contains. But that call may not be finished yet, when you try to access your `products.bestSeller`

Comment: ok, I edit the Question with getAll function img

Comment: Oh so it is a race condition. You should try changing the getAll function to be async. I modified my answer. Pleas check out if it works. Clearly what you get in return is not the data but the promise of the data.

Comment: no it dose not work, and there is error in const fetchData

Answer (score 0):

You have a race condtion in your code. The initial render happens befor you upload the data with fetch.

```
import ProductItem from './ProductItem';
import {getAll} from '../../api/product';

class Products extends Component {
   state ={
      products :[]
   };
componentDidMount(){
    fetchData()
}

const fetchData = async () => {
    let data = await getAll()
    this.setState({
        products :data
    })
}



render() {
    
    return (
    <div className="container">
        <div className="head-with-border"><h2>New Arrival</h2></div>
        <div className="products">
            {(this.state.products.bestSeller 
                ? this.state.products.bestSeller 
                : []
             ).map(product =>
                <div className={"product"} key={product.id}>
                <ProductItem product={product}/>
                </div>
            )}
        
        </div>

    </div>
    )
  }
 }
 export default Products;
```

Comment: the error disappeared, but the products did not appear in the screen

Comment: Could you please post the console.log output of the data returned by getAll function?

Answer (score 0):

You need to check for the default empty state:

```
import ProductItem from './ProductItem';
import {getAll} from '../../api/product';

class Products extends Component {
   state ={
      products: {}
   };
componentDidMount(){
    getAll().then(data =>{
        this.setState({
            products :data
        })
        
    });
}
render() {
    const { bestSeller } = this.state.products;
    
    return (
        <div className="container">
            <div className="head-with-border"><h2>New Arrival</h2></div>
            <div className="products">
                {bestSeller && bestSeller.map(product =>
                    <div className={"product"} key={product.id}>
                    <ProductItem product={product}/>
                    </div>
                )}
            
            </div>

        </div>
    )
  }
 }
 export default Products;
```

I also changed your default product state to an empty object instead of a array to align it with the data structure you are working with.

Comment: the error disappeared, but the products did not appear in the screen